# Oracle ODP.NET 11.1 for 64 bit for windows 2008

Tags: oracle, odp.net

Does anyone know where i can download ODP.NET version 11.1 for 64 bit? They only list version 10g and version 11.2 on their download site.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Or will ODP.NET version 11.2 work OK against Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7 - 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

11.2 works fine even against 10gR2 (that's what we have here).  However, to my knowledge, the 64 bit version only comes in an xcopy flavor:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

I've documented my experience with the xcopy install here:
http://www.brothersincode.com/post/Oracle-ODPnet-xcopy-deployment-for-aspnet.aspx

I just recently installed this on 2008 R2 myself and it went fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this version on a Win2008R2 x64 production server with SQL 2008R2 Standard and it's working fine: [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle11g/112010/win64_11gR2_client.zip)

It will work OK against Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7 - 64bit.

For more info, check this: [Master Note for ODP.Net (Oracle Data Provider for .Net)](http://blogs.oracle.com/db/entry/master_note_for_odpnet_oracle_data_provider_for_net)